# Uiscrollview by default left to right?

Tags: uiscrollview

i have an uiscrollview with an imageview. the user can flick on the uiscrollview from right to left. can i make the user flick from left to right on the uiscrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set 'setContentOffset' to (0,0)